# how to retain text box and submit button and display the output in the same page

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

views.py

```
def nslookups(request):
dig = NameForm
r = []
#dig = form_class(request.POST or None)
if request.method == 'POST':
   dig = NameForm(request.POST)
   if dig.is_valid():
       fqdn = dig.cleaned_data['lookup']
       answers = dns.resolver.query( fqdn,'A')
       for a in answers:
            r.append(a.address)
            print(r)
       return render(request,'accounts/dns.html',{'nslookup': r})

else:
    dig = NameForm()
return render(request, 'accounts/dns.html',{'dig': dig})
```

dns.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<h3>Welcome</h3>
<h3>DNS</h3>

<form  method="post">
   {% csrf_token %}
   {{ dig }}
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
{{ nslookup }}
{% endblock %}
```

Requirement is to input dns record in text box and then display the result in the same page along with text box and submit button.

Comment: You need to use ajax here for data submission. More clarification is needed in the question.

Comment: You need to use ajax. That's all